# Rails app using SASS importing CSS from external gems not processing Sprockets directives

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets, sass-rails

I feel like this must be a relatively common issue, but my Google-foo has thus far failed me.

I have a Rails 4 app where I am using SASS for my CSS. I have a couple of gems that I am (forced) to use that primarily contain CSS. Let's say gem C has an `index.css` file that contains Sprockets directives for the CSS of that gem. When I `@import gem-x/index` my `application.css` file will contain simply the text of those Sprockets directives.

The only solution I have been able to find is to look at the source of the external gems so that I can manually `@import` each CSS file directly, e.g.

```
@import gem-x/file1
@import gem-x/file2
@import gem-x/file3
```

This is both tedious and requires me to know the structure of the assets for each external gem that does not provide SASS for consumption directly.

Is there any way to have Sprockets and the asset pipeline process the `index.css` files of these external gems when I `@import` them, rather than simply plopping there text into my `application.css`?

---

Edit:

This behavior appears to be tied to a breaking change in `sass-rails` 5+: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/297

That thread is a year old tho. Are there any workarounds or solutions these days?

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with importing all files from the gem instead of a specific file, you can simply do:

> @import "*";